# Alternative for SCD2 transform in SAS DI

Tags: sas

Is it possible to replace the SCD2 transformation in SAS DI studio?

I use it to track the changes to dimension data, but with huge tables (about 10 millions rows/observations), this is very time consuming. Just wondering on the best solution to use other loading instead of scd2 to save time.

Is only the SCD2 tracking historical changes?

Thanks,

Comment: Could you paste the code generated by DI studio here (probably after replacing the company specific information with placeholders)?

Comment: You could roll your own.  You could also take a look at https://datacontroller.io (disclaimer - we built it) as this comes with an SCD2 loader that is much more efficient than the one provided in DI Studio.  Works on bitemporal tables too.